# How to limit to just one result per condition when looking through multiple OR/IN conditions in the WHERE clause (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

For Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE Country IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK')
```

I want to LIMIT 1 for each of the countries in my IN clause so I only see a total of 3 rows: One customer for per country (1 German, 1 France, 1 UK). Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Which _one_ of the customers from each country would you like to see?

Comment: Please include schema, especially the primary key field so we can provide a relevant answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, a simple `GROUP BY` would suffice for this type of solution, however as you have specified that you want to include *ALL* of the columns in the result, then we can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to provide a value to filter on.

> As a general rule it is important to specify the column to *sort on* (`ORDER BY`) for all windowing or paged queries to make the result repeatable.

*As no schema has been supplied, I have used `Name` as the field to sort on for the window, please update that (or the question) with any other field you would like, the **PK** is a good candidate if you have nothing else to go on.*

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY Name) AS _rn
    FROM Customers
    WHERE Country IN ('Germany', 'France', 'UK')
)
WHERE _rn = 1
```

The `PARTITION BY` forces the `ROW_NUMBER` to be counted across all records with the same `Country` value, starting at 1, so in this case we only select the rows that get a *row number* (aliased as `_rn`) of 1.

The `WHERE` clause could have been in the outer query if you really want to, but `ROW_NUMBER()` can only be specified in the `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` clauses of the query, so to use it as a filter criteria we are forced to wrap the results in some way.